# Passing n number of input to a GET method of a REST service

Tags: list, rest, get, jersey

I am trying to write a **REST service** with **Jersey** where the GET method should write me a list of objects. The input to the GET method should take the ids of the list.
Say I will pass n numbers of `EmployeeId` and the service should return me a list of employees.

If it is not possible to have `@Consumes` in the GET method, will there be any problem in using other methods of http like PUT or POST to retrieve the list of objects?

Comment: What's the issue with `@Consumes`? It specifies the content-type, what does it have to do with list of `GET` parameters?

Comment: Can you post the GET method that you've already written?

Comment: Place the scoping information in query parameters. You can use the `@QueryParam` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `POST` and `PUT` for resource retrieval contradicts the conventions established for the usage of REST over HTTP. Switching to either of them just for the sake of using a `@Consumes` annotation is simply wrong.

If you need to provide additional scoping information for a collection of resources, place it in the URL. Specifically, you can use query parameters. It's a common pattern to implement pagination this way (by providing some limit and offset parameters). Your use case is very similar.

Let's assume this is the URL of a collection of employee resources

```
GET http://www.example.com/employees
```

A single employee could be fetched like this:

```
GET http://www.example.com/employees/id1
```

If you want to retrieve several employees, you could use a query string like this:

```
GET http://www.example.com/employees?ids=id1;id3;id8
```

The identifiers do not need to be delimited by semicolons, this is just an example of a way you could fetch them. Remember that it's treated as a single parameter! You'll have to split the values.

Here's how you could read such a list from the URL above

```
@Path("employees")
@GET
public Response getEmployees(@QueryParam("ids") String employees){
   List<String> ids = Arrays.asList(employes.split(";"));
   // Validate the ids, get data from a database, 
   // prepare a response and return it
}
```

Parsing the list can be cumbersome, especially if you want to validate the ids somehow. Jersey has a neat feature you can use here. If a class has a single-string-parameter constructor or a `SomeType parse(String)` method, it can be injected by the framework by parsing the string passed as a parameter (`QueryParam`, `PathParam`, `FormParam`, etc.)

You can take advantage of it to make your resource class cleaner.

```
@Path("employees")
@GET
public Response getEmployees(@QueryParam("ids") Employees e){
   doFancyStaffWithAValidListOfEmployees(e.asList());
   //prepare a response
}
```

Where `Employees` is a class with a String constructor or a parse method, containing all the splitting and validation logic, possibly even some database queries.

[Here's a nice article on writing such parameter classes](http://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-parameter-classes/)